# PHP + sha256 + cert

Tags: php, sha256

Necesito firmar un documento XML.

Esta es la estructura del XML:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:smk="http://****.es" xmlns:oper="http://****.es/OperationCode" xmlns:typ="http:/***.es/Types">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <smk:operationCode>
         <oper:operationCodeRequest>
            <typ:Id>?</typ:Id>
            <typ:Date>?</typ:Date>
            <typ:Code>?</typ:Code>
            <oper:Val>?</oper:Val>
         </oper:operationCodeRequest>
      </smk:operationCode>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Y esta es la estructura XML que necesito:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:oper="http://***.es/OperationStatus" xmlns:smk="http://***.es" 
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:typ="http://***.es/Types">
   <soapenv:Header>   <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="X509-194D65A85DD46269DF..">MII...znqx</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
   <ds:Signature Id="SIG-194D65A85DD46269DF..." xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
   <ds:SignedInfo>
   <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
    <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="oper smk soapenv typ" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
   </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
   <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
   <ds:Reference URI="#id-194D65A85DD46269DF1..">
    <ds:Transforms>
     <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
      <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="oper smk typ" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
     </ds:Transform>
    </ds:Transforms>
    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
         <ds:DigestValue>rmJDCesz4UZvAM6auZ1S...v4=</ds:DigestValue>
   </ds:Reference>
   </ds:SignedInfo>
   <ds:SignatureValue>wtd...uA==</ds:SignatureValue>
<ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-194D65A85DD46269DF...">
 <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-194D65A85DD46269DF...">
  <wsse:Reference URI="#X509-194D65A85DD46269DF.." ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
 </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
 </ds:KeyInfo>
 </ds:Signature>
 </wsse:Security>
 </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body wsu:Id="id-194D65A85DD46269DF..." xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
      <smk:operationCode>
         <oper:operationCodeRequest>
            <typ:Id>?</typ:Id>
            <typ:Date>?</typ:Date>
            <typ:Code>?</typ:Code>
            <oper:Val>?</oper:Val>
         </oper:operationCodeRequest>
      </smk:operationCode>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

¿Alguien puede echarme una mano sobre como empezar?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: para firmar el documento usas un certificado p12 ?

Comment: si es asi te podria servir: https://github.com/odoo-ecuador/odoo-ecuador/tree/10.0/l10n_ec_einvoice/xades/firma

Comment: Hola Diego, muchas gracias. Me has mandado una solucion en java, yo necesito el script en PHP, ¿puedes darme alguna idea o contacto para solucionarlo?

Comment: esos link que te envie son referenciales puedes ver como se realizaron a mi me sirvio , dado que yo uso python